How to change the SUPL server used in Android
As far as I googled (correct me if I'm wrong), most Android phones today use Google SUPL server: supl.google.com with 7276 or 7275 port. There is a little company that is developing their own SUPL server so it can be used instead of Google.
My goal is to change SUPL server used on my phone to that SUPL server.
My phone: Samsung Galaxy A52 (model SM-A525F/DS), Android version 13, firmware version A525FXXU5DWB6, rooted with Magisk (to be able to modify system files).
Most sites say that in order to do what I want I need to change gps.conf file, located at system/vendor/etc/gps.conf. I was able to change it with custom Magisk module, which basically replaces original gps.conf file with my own.
The changes I made in the original file:
SUPL_HOST=supl.my_supl_server_here.com
SUPL_PORT=7276

LPP_PROFILE = 1

A_GLONASS_POS_PROTOCOL_SELECT = 0x4

AGPS_CONFIG_INJECT = 1

I rebooted the phone after changes were made, and with GPS Test app cleared and updated AGPS data. I hoped that my phone would be able to initiate SUPL session to query information from SUPL server (server SUPL_HOST in config file above). But it didn't happen, the server didn't recieve anything from my device.
So, how can I actually change the SUPL server my phone uses for A-GPS information?

https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Alt-Repo/supl-replacer could help if your phone is rooted with Magisk. Otherwise, you can still have a look at the code (I didn’t).
Would you care to disclose the name of the company (and more importantly the server)?
